# Private prerender server and angular js issue

Tags: node.js, angularjs, prerender

Hello I'm using open source prerender middleware, as I installed it on CentOS 7 server as follows:

```
 git clone https://github.com/prerender/prerender.git
 cd prerender
 npm install
```

The configuration I am using in server.js file is quite simple:

```
var prerender = require('./lib');

var server = prerender({
        chromeLocation: '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable',
        chromeFlags: ['--no-sandbox','--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--remote-debugging-port=9222', '--hide-scrollbars','--disable-setuid-
sandbox' ]

});



server.use(prerender.sendPrerenderHeader());
// server.use(prerender.blockResources());
server.use(prerender.removeScriptTags());
server.use(prerender.httpHeaders());
server.use(require('prerender-memory-cache'))



server.start();
```

I'm also using the prerender-apache middware along with prerender and angular js app

```
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "token"

     <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
   
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot|Sitemaps|Google-Structured-Data-Testing-Tool|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/(.*)/
        
        # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML

            RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*)  http://some.ip:3000/https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [P,L]


        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot|Sitemaps|Google-Structured-Data-Testing-Tool|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/rootDirectory/ 
 
        # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
        #RewriteRule ^(.*)  http:/some.ip:3000/https://%{HTTP_HOST} [P,L]


    </IfModule>
```

So first I was trying to run it with forever.js with following command in prerender folder:

```
forever start server.js
```

It works properly for a few hours and then a problem arises that I can't figure out why it occurred. Many chrome sessions start to be created and the server RAM starts to decrease until the server stops, I read that the flag: '--no-sandbox causes this problem and I have removed it, but then I got another problem when I start server.js forever I got :

```
Starting Prerender
Starting Chrome
Prerender server accepting requests on port 3000
Chrome connection closed... restarting Chrome
Chrome died immediately after restart... stopping Prerender
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 0
```

I'm using

```
node.js v12.14.0
Google Chrome 85.0.4183.102
```

I'll be grateful if someone could help thanks.

Comment: I had a similar issue with my react application. It turns out that chrome was creating process zombies which were eating up CPU & memory resources. As a workaround you can add a crontab which will kill chrome zombies once a day or week.

Comment: I see, what could be the reason chrome creating that process zombies?